# Create a copy of an image - python

Tags: python, image, binary, byte

I'm trying to read data from an image file and writing it to a new file - to make a copy.

Here is my code to read the data of the original image and to write every byte to the new image:

```
file = open("image2.png", "w")
with open("image.png", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        byte = f.read(1)
        if not byte:
            break
        file.write(byte)
```

Now, it does create a new file named "image2.png" but when I try to open it I get an error that says the image has been corrupted or damaged.

How can I read the data of an image and writing it to a new file?

Comment: Use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) if you work with images, or [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.8/).

Comment: also that's strange because your code works for me.

Comment: I'd assume you should open the file in `wb` mode.

Comment: really? Becuase it doesn't work for me

Comment: Ok it works now! I only had to change "w" to "wb" ! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Using `shutil`:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy("image.png","image2.png")
```

Or as you have it:

```
file = open("image2.png", "wb")
with open("image.png", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        byte = f.read(1)
        if not byte:
            break
        file.write(byte[0])
```

Comment: Yea but how do I get the raw data of an image? I'm familiar with the shutil module