# How to download image from a variable?

Tags: python, image, file, directory, download

This is my python code:

```
image = /folder/image.png
def download_image(path):
 # insert download image proccess here
download_image(/anotherfolder/imagecopy.png)
```

What I want to do, is to download the image from */folder* to */anotherfolder* as **imagecopy.png**
I don't have an URL to the image. I just want to copy it.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: [How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know) answers your question.

Comment: Start with a better example. `image = /folder/image.png` is not valid Python code.

Comment: if you open a terminal in /images/ and run `python3 -m http.server 9000` then you can open a browser, type `localhost:9000` into the address bar and you should see alisting of the directory contents. From there you can right click on the file and 'save as' where you like and with what name you like.

Comment: `/folder/image.png` is also not a valid URL.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to copy it there, or place it there, I want to download it like it was a file from the internet.

Downloading is just copying the file from a server computer to your computer. It looks like you are trying to make a copy of an image on your computer to another place on your computer. "Downloading" is copying it.

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation, I improved on the question

Comment: This thread should answer your question. But instead of using "image.png" use the path "folder/image.png". 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515913/create-a-copy-of-an-image-python